# Can mutual auth and x509 co exist in same spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm running two jvms. One with webapp jwt auth and another one for mutual auth. It creates lot of overhead to the hosting machine? Is it possible to auth different paths with different auth mode in spring?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [multiple filter chains](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity), one for each path:

```java
@Bean
@Order(0)
SecurityFilterChain jwtPaths(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers((requests) -> requests.mvcMatchers("/jwt-paths/**"))
        // configuration for paths that use JWT auth

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain x509Paths(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers((requests) -> requests.mvcMatchers("/x509Paths/**"))
        // configuration for paths that use X.509 auth

    return http.build();
}
```